# iOS14 How to blurred widget background

Tags: widget

just like system batteries or Siri Shortcuts widget.

[image: batteries widget]

Answer (score 1):

An Apple engineer replied to this question to say that it is currently impossible for 3rd party app developers to blur the backgrounds of their Widgets.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655990